# Compare number to a column and if it's equal or less then write text assigned for that row compared

Tags: excel, compare

For example I have 3 kind of electrical wires that have different "ampacity".

- Cable 1 -> 10 A
- Cable 2 -> 15 A
- Cable 3 -> 20 A

Then if I need to transfer 17 A a cell needs to recommend "Cable 3". In case it is 15 A it should recommend "Cable 2".
Tried this `=IF(MAX(D28:D35)<P51,"True", "False")` but although I have a number greater than P51 in that column it shows "False". Of course the idea is that "True" should be the kind of cable for a value in range `D28:D35`

Any comment would be truly appreciated!

Comment: @Jeeped wouldn't `17 A` return `Cable 2` with Vlookup with True, instead of the intended Cable 3, with the current data? obviously one could put the minimum threshold to change Cable 1 --> 0, Cable 2 --> 10.0001, bla bla bla.  But as the data is I believe one of your famous INDEX/AGGREGATES is what is needed.

Comment: Yes, you are completely correct in that.

Comment: @ScottCraner tried with this `=INDEX($C$28:$C$35,MATCH(D38,$D$28:$D$35,1))` but for a `187` cable it returns a `150`, while it should be a `200` cable. [Example](http://imgur.com/a/lR8B3)

Comment: I am away from my computer at the moment, so this is not tested: `=INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($D$28:$D$35)/($D$28:$D$35>=D38),1))`

Comment: @ScottCraner problem was that I had to inverse the column order of capacities in order to use "-1" option of MATCH. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Match with -1 to find >= lookup value, but write the lookup array in descending order:

```
Column A     Column B   
Cable 3       20
Cable 2       15
Cable 1       10
```

`=INDEX($A$1:$A$3,MATCH(F1,$B$1:$B$3,-1))`
F1 is the number that you need the corresponding Cable